# Security practices and CPanel

Tags: ftp, cpanel

I have started being more vigilant about one person - one set of credentials for all types of logins. But it seems that many CPanel setups frustrate that practice for SFTP because SSH is only allowed on the primary FTP account. That means that everyone in an organization who needs to move files will be using the same login. So, then we have the choice of 1) use FTP - less secure, 2) have everyone use the same login (less secure.)

Is the only answer to use a different web host?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you enable TLS Encryption Support on your server with the FTP, You can enable this through WHM >> Service Configuration >> FTP Server Configuration

Here are the some configuration docs : https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/FTP+Server+Configuration

Comment: Just to be sure I understand correctly, the reason I would do this is so that a plain FTP connection would then be encrypted, by-passing the need for SFTP?